# Thinking I should be allowed to `delete` a pointer but an error is thrown `block in use`

Tags: c++, pointers, dynamic-allocation

Consider this function:

```
bool RemoveElement(const T2& e2)
{
    bool match = false;

    for (int i = 0; i < _trenutno; i++)
    {
        if (*_elementi2[i] == e2){

            match = true;

            for (int j = i; j < _trenutno - 1; j++)
            {
                _elementi1[j] = _elementi1[j + 1];
                _elementi2[j] = _elementi2[j + 1];

                // SOLUTION: The two lines above are not correct.
                // Instead of assigning addresses, I should have assigned
                // values, ie. dereference them like below:

                // *_elementi1[j] = *_elementi1[j + 1];
                // *_elementi2[j] = *_elementi2[j + 1];

            }
        }
    }


    if (match)
    {
        _trenutno--;

        //delete _elementi1[_trenutno];
        _elementi1[_trenutno] = nullptr;

        //delete _elementi2[_trenutno];
        _elementi2[_trenutno] = nullptr;
    }

    return match;
}
```

FYI, the pointers themselves (see below). I'm trying in the above function delete values behind this particular pair of pointers (last element) using `delete` because otherwise I believe memory leak would occur?

```
template<class T1, class T2, int max>
class Kolekcija
{
    T1* _elementi1[max];
    T2* _elementi2[max];
    int _trenutno;
public:
    Kolekcija()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < max; i++)
        {
            _elementi1[i] = nullptr;
            _elementi2[i] = nullptr;
        }
        _trenutno = 0;
    }
    //  ...

    ~Kolekcija()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < _trenutno; i++){
            delete _elementi1[i]; _elementi1[i] = nullptr;
            delete _elementi2[i]; _elementi2[i] = nullptr;
        }
    }
    // ....
```

Why is this happening, I'd like to learn more and better understand pointers.

Comment: Whether or not `delete` must be used to avoid leaking memory depends entirely on how these pointers were initialized. Which you did not explain, so no authoritative answer is possible here. Furthermore, this is what `std::shared_ptr` is for.

Comment: The code seems to remove one element from the array by shifting all following elements one to the front. You should then delete the removed element, instead you try to delete the last one of the array.

Comment: Your algorithm is wrong. It would not free the removed element (see Karsten's comment). Furthermore you should check a pointer everytime before you free the memory, so write `if (ptr != nullptr) delete ptr`.

Comment: What is `T1* _elementi1[6];`? Is it pointer to C++ array (or array of pointers to array?). Why you didn't use `T1 _elementi1[6];`? It seems that `RemoveElement` is incorrect itself. But instead of fix it I recomend you ro use std::vector or other appropriate collection.

Comment: I don't like how the variables are declared as pointers to arrays, and then indexed using `[]` as if they were arrays. Are you sure about this part?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I updated the code
I don't want to remove the value from the "removed" pointer, but to shift them to the left after the deletion point, and them reset to nullptr the very last one.
But now I realize - I should dereference when trying to assign the next one's values, instead I'm assigning the addresses, right?
This was like talking to a rubber duck experience, I guess I found the problem?

Comment: No, the shown code still does not explain how these pointers have been initialized to point to whatever they're pointing to.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I'll show you the function if you want but first, I found the issue. I was simply assigning addresses instead of dereferencing to assign values: `*_elementi1[j] = *_elementi1[j + 1]`

Comment: Setting those pointers to `nullptr` in the destructor is pointless, since they all go away when the destructor returns.

Comment: @developer10 in your case `(*_elementi1)[j] = (*_elementi1)[j + 1]`. But it is pointless since you have to use `std::vector` :)

Comment: @PeteBecker Thanks for the input but we're being taught that, although it's not required - it's good practice. Therefore I'm using it there when practicing.

Comment: @DmitriyZapevalov Well, I can't use `vector` in this particular case because if my professor puts it like this - I can't change it. I believe the class itself (`Collection`) mimicks the `vector` functionality as it has both AddElement() and RemoveElement() methods

Comment: @DmitriyZapevalov Also, do you think assigning values like so causes any memory leak or it is safe?

Comment: Then use the `T1 _elementi1[6];` definition. It is an array of T1s.

Comment: @developer10 - writing pointless code is not good practice.

Comment: @DmitriyZapevalov I can't because we're given the code as it is, no changes from our side. That's why I'm practicing this in the form my professor will provide the problem on the exam.

Comment: @PeteBecker I tend to agree. But what use is there for me if my professor (I'd like him to know your opinion) will deduct some points thinking I should have done it on the exam. Thanks for pointing that out to me, I appreciate it and will bear it in mind.

Comment: @developer10 then either they're not really a teacher or there is some misunderstanding between you two. Either way, I feel you, this isn't what university education should be like.

Comment: @iksemyonov - while I agree with that sentiment, there are many misconceptions being taught to beginning programmers. "My professor insists that I do it this way" is, unfortunately, a valid answer. The transition from student to professional programmer often requires unlearning some things.

Comment: I've realized that `int* array[5]` is array to pointers to int. So fields defenitions are correct. Sorry for previous messages.

Comment: @UniversE, minor nitpick: the standard requires that a delete call has no effect if the argument is a null pointer value, so there's no need to test.

Comment: @Aenimated1 that is very interesting. Didn't know that. Do you know how well the compilers respect that requirement?

Comment: @UniversE, I haven't tested it explicitly on many different compilers, but I've used various versions of gcc and MS Visual Studio's compiler and haven't encountered any problems despite relying on this behavior.  I would guess it would be hard to find a compiler that doesn't respect the requirement since many developers habitually rely on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your class is the `data owner` and you want to remove some element:

1. Find index of element `(_elementi1[nFound] == searchValue)`
2. Delete this element from heap `delete _elementi1[nFound];`
3. Set element's value to `nullptr` `_elementi1[nFound] = nullptr;`
4. Only then move trailing elements in place of removed item.

This sequence will protect you against memory leaks in `Remove` method.

Destructor will clean other heap allocated values (assuming `_trenutno` is actual `count`):

```
    for (int i = 0; i < _trenutno; i++)
    {
        delete _elementi1[i]; _elementi1[i] = nullptr;
        delete _elementi2[i]; _elementi2[i] = nullptr;
    }
```

Deleting `nullptr` is `safe`.

So my version of `Remove()`:

```
bool RemoveElement(const T2& e2)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < _trenutno; i++)
    {
        if (*_elementi2[i] == e2) 
        {
            delete _elementi1[i];
            _elementi1[i] = nullptr;
            delete _elementi2[i];
            _elementi2[i] = nullptr;

            for (int j = i; j < _trenutno - 1; j++)
            {
                _elementi1[j] = _elementi1[j + 1];
                _elementi2[j] = _elementi2[j + 1];
            }
            _trenutno--;
            return true; //found
        }
    }
    return false; //not found
}
```

I'm assuming that your collection is the `data owner`. So you `have to` `delete` all pointers that was passed to it.
Simple example (we'r adding 3 values):

```
int* elements[max] = {0};
elements[0] = new int(4); //0x00FF1F
elements[1] = new int(5); //0x00FF2F
elements[2] = new int(6); //0x00FF3F
_trenutno = 3;
```

We have to `delete` all 3 `int*`

If no `Remove` was called destructor will handle it (delete from `0` to `2`).

If we call `Remove(5)`:

1. Found index of `5` value `i == 1`
2. Call `delete elements[1]` that means `releaze memory at address 0x00FF2F`
3. Make shift: `elements[1] = elements[2]`

Now our array is:

```
elements[0]; //0x00FF1F
elements[1]; //0x00FF3F
elements[2]; //0x00FF3F
```

And _trenutno = 2;

So destructor will remove pointers from '0' to '1'.

That is all 3 pointers where deleted!

Comment: But, is there anything wrong with my approach, in terms of possible memory leak? Because I need to preserve the order in which elements were added, thus I'm shifting them to left, overwritting the one to be removed with the value of the next one. I'm doing so by replacing the value of that pointer to be removed with the value of the next one (shifting to left). So, in your opinion, is this a good approach? No memory leak?

Comment: I've added point `4`. Your approach is staying but you have to `delete` removing item (both in 1 and 2 collection) before shifting. Also check questions about `Detecting memory leaks`. It is easy to activate and you will be sure that program works correct.

Comment: That sounds so odd. Am I not simply overwriting some value with another value? Yes, the element itself may be an int, or an object but anyway. I fail to see how overwriting can leak memory because I'm keeping the pointer itself intact. I'm very inexperienced so I'll believe what you're saying and will try to find stuff on detecting memory leaks. Thanks!

Comment: You'r not overwriting values. You'r not working with values at all (only in == operator). You'r working with pointers. I'll edit answer to explain.

Comment: OK, I edited what you just edited to show what I meant (in case you're not aware of what I'm trying to say).

Comment: I hope it is clear that you don't have to rewrite values but pointers. Value could be 1Gb length while pointer is still small.

Comment: So, instead of doing all this fuss with assigning values, I simply delete the pointer to be removed, and assign it the address of the next one? Yep, that seems legit. Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome. Always try to "play" program in you mind (or in a debugger) to understand how it works and find errors.

Answer (score 0):

Here you have many problems, at first you need to delete item , and then set nullptr value for that position in array, and if I want to use array of T1 and T2 like in your case , than I would use vector instead of simple array

Comment: There's a reason I'm using raw pointers and this class `Collection` (college). Also, do you think it's safe (memory-leak-wise) to just assign values instead of addresses when shifting pointers to the left (as I explained in my last comment above - which solved the issue when I put those * there)?